# What is the point of `copy`?

Tags: julia

I am very confused about the purpose of `copy`. As illustrated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017533/what-is-the-difference-between-copy-and-deep-copy-in-julia), `copy` creates a shallow copy whereas `deepcopy` creates an independent object. If you used `copy`, the underlying references remain unchanged. If I did `b = copy(a)` and altered `a`, then `b` would change as well.

Then what is the purpose of `copy`? We already have `=`. Is there something that `copy` can do but `=` cannot do?

Comment: I don't know the language but maybe `array b = copy(array a)` differs from `array b = array a` when adding new elements?

Comment: Your statement is incorrect. If you alter `a`, `b` will stay unchanged.

Comment: @DNF, No! [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60017711/11747148).

Comment: @Shayan Actually @DNF is not entirely wrong. Try `a = ones(3); b = copy(a); a[3] = 111`. Why is there such a difference between the link and this example?

Comment: @user1691278, I guess the point is the outer and the inner structure in that case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making sense of how Julia copies variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72912336/making-sense-of-how-julia-copies-variables)

Comment: @Shayan My statement is correct. If you _mutate an element of_ `a`, `b` can be changed (in those cases where this is possible), but if you alter `a` _itself_ by replacing an element, `b` does not see this.

Comment: [*Your statement is incorrect.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74562790/what-is-the-point-of-copy?noredirect=1#comment131618061_74562790). I said No, because of this sentence.

Comment: @Shayan I stand by my statement. I won't continue beyond this point.

Comment: @DNF I didn't ask to either.

Comment: https://youtu.be/yeaTNPKqRTo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.copy) says:

> `copy(x)`
>
> Create a shallow copy of `x`: the outer structure is copied, but not all internal values. For example, copying an array produces a new array with identically-same elements as the original.

So if you do `b = copy(a)`, then replace an element in `b`, `a`'s contents are unchanged, because it's a different object. If you just did `b = a`, they'd both refer to the same array, and any replacement would show up regardless of whether you looked in `a` or `b`.

Example:

```
> a = [1, 2]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2

> b = a
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2

> c = copy(a)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2

> a[1] = 42
42

> a
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 42
  2

> b
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 42
  2

> c
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2

>
```

In the above, `a` refers to an array with `[1, 2]` in it (to start with). `b` is just another variable referring to the same array, but `c` is a shallow copy — a *different* array with (initially) the same elements in it. When we replace the `1` in `a[1]` with `42`, we see that replacement whether we look through `a` or `b` because they're both looking at the same object, but `c` is a different object and is unaffected.

---

In a comment you've asked:

> Why does this differ from the chosen answer in the link in my post?

The [answer you refer to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60017711/157247) isn't modifying the top-level array (`a`) that we're either assigning to `b` (`b = a`) or *copying* (`b = copy(a)`). Since it's modifying the contents of an array *within* it, you see that modification.

Here's a conceptual picture of memory after `a = [1, 2]`:

```
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
a−−−−−−−−>|   (Array)   |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          | Index 1: 1  |
          | Index 2: 2  |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Then after `b = a`:

```
a−−−−+
     |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     +−−−>|   (Array)   |
     |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
b−−−−+    | Index 1: 1  |
          | Index 2: 2  |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Then after `c = copy(a)`:

```
a−−−−+    
     |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     +−−−>|   (Array)   |
     |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
b−−−−+    | Index 1: 1  |
          | Index 2: 2  |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
c−−−−−−−−>|   (Array)   |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          | Index 1: 1  |
          | Index 2: 2  |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Then after `a[1] = 42`:

```
a−−−−+    
     |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     +−−−>|   (Array)   |
     |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
b−−−−+    | Index 1: 42 |
          | Index 2: 2  |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
c−−−−−−−−>|   (Array)   |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          | Index 1: 1  |
          | Index 2: 2  |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

In contrast, the answer you refer to was dealing with an array of arrays:

```
# The `a`, `b`, an `c` from the other answer (without the [4,5,6] array)
          
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
a−−−−−−−−>|   (Array)    |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      
          | Index 1:     |−−−−−+
          | Index 2: ... |     |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |
                               |
                               |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                               +−−−−>|   (Array)    |
                               |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |     | Index 1: 1   |
b−−−−−−−−>|   (Array)    |     |     | Index 2: 2   |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |     | Index 3: 3   |
          | Index 1:     |−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          | Index 2: ... |            
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      
c−−−−−−−−>|   (Array)    |      
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          | Index 1:     |−−−−−−−−−−>|   (Array)    |
          | Index 2: ... |           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+           | Index 1: 1   |
                                     | Index 2: 2   |
                                     | Index 3: 3   |
                                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

So when they did `a[1][1] = 111`, it changed the one `a` and `b` were (indirectly) pointing to, but not the one `c` was pointing to:

```
# The `a`, `b`, an `c` from the other answer (without the [4,5,6] array)
          
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
a−−−−−−−−>|   (Array)    |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      
          | Index 1:     |−−−−−+
          | Index 2: ... |     |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |
                               |
                               |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                               +−−−−>|   (Array)    |
                               |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |     | Index 1: 111 |
b−−−−−−−−>|   (Array)    |     |     | Index 2: 2   |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |     | Index 3: 3   |
          | Index 1:     |−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          | Index 2: ... |            
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      
c−−−−−−−−>|   (Array)    |      
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          | Index 1:     |−−−−−−−−−−>|   (Array)    |
          | Index 2: ... |           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+           | Index 1: 1   |
                                     | Index 2: 2   |
                                     | Index 3: 3   |
                                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Comment: Follow up question: if I did `a = ones(3); b = copy(a); a[3] = 111`, `b` would not change. Why does this differ from the chosen answer in the link in my post?

Comment: Assuming you mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017533/what-is-the-difference-between-copy-and-deep-copy-in-julia/60017711#60017711 , the important thing there is that `a` is a container of containers. `b = copy(a)` is a new outer container, and replacing `a[1]` will not affect `b`, exactly as above. Both examples also have `a[2] === b[2]`, but in that one, these inner objects are themselves mutable containers, which are shared.

Comment: @user1691278 - I've updated my answer with a contrast between them and with diagrams.